# How to know if you got blocked from a website for web scraping?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I used this beautifulsoup code on a website:

```
headers = ({'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36'})
funda = "https://www.funda.nl/koop/amsterdam/"
response = get(funda, headers=headers)
print(response)
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

print(response.text)
```

and I am getting this response.text back:

```
<Response [200]>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; url=/distil_r_captcha.html?requestId=01fe7635-8c6e-404f-b905-fd8d854fa40c&httpReferrer=%2Fkoop%2Famsterdam%2F" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(window){
        try {
            if (typeof sessionStorage !== 'undefined'){
                sessionStorage.setItem('distil_referrer', document.referrer);
            }
        } catch (e){}
    })(window);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fundadst.rvezxdcvwbzdewcsbar.js" defer></script><style type="text/css">#d__fFH{position:absolute;top:-5000px;left:-5000px}#d__fF{font-family:serif;font-size:200px;visibility:hidden}#suuazwruefzeaa{display:none!important}</style></head>
<body>
<div id="distilIdentificationBlock">&nbsp;</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Did I get blocked? Is this block permanent and can I do something about it?

Thank you

Comment: Looks like a specific anti-bot service, some discussion [here](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash/issues/195)

Comment: There are a lot of tricks to spidering.  You may want to try different user agents, different IP addresses, etc.  Some sites just block anything automated (check there robots.txt file), sometimes it is the owner of the site, sometimes it is the host of the site.  You can always email the company.  _Most_ companies want to be spidered, it drives traffic.  But the hosts often don't want their customer sites spidered (just costs them bandwidth money).

Comment: You're not blocked You've encountered the infamous `distil_r_captcha` and it is permanent. The solution is to try different user agents and/or headers. I know of at least one that works, but I can't list it here because distil could block it if I do. It's something you've to discover for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like you are trying to scrape a javascript rendered site using the python requests library? This library is only able to scrape static sites, which is why you are receiving a JS block in your response.

You should consider switching to one of the packages below:

- [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) (with a headless browser)
- [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) (Which crawls the web using Spiders)

There are a couple other libraries out there that wrap a chrome driver, but not many are maintained.

Here is a medium tutorial on scraping with selenium: https://medium.com/@hoppy/how-to-test-or-scrape-javascript-rendered-websites-with-python-selenium-a-beginner-step-by-c137892216aa

Here is a medium tutorial for using web crawlers to scrape:
https://medium.com/@djerahahmedrafik/web-scraping-fundamentals-using-scrapy-84a1e64b5ec

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks a lot! I will try it and let you know if the block goes away. the guys in this forum linked earlier mentioned selenium gets flagged quite quickly by JS https://www.blackhatworld.com/seo/python-scraping-distil-protected-sites.988967/  but I haven't tried that personally

Comment: No problem. Let me know how everything goes.